# Why is my spyder kernel crashing after opening a chrome browser instance with my default profile on a Python program? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, crash

After the very exhaustive research of today, I managed to understand and make a simple program that will use the `selenium` module to open a chrome window with my user data and default profile, here:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400') #resolution
root.title("Bulkdozer") #Name of this program
root.attributes('-topmost', True) #keep the program's window top-most

opt = Options() #selenium options
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+r"C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default") #PATH profile
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Profile to use
s = Service('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')

def open_chrome_profile():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
    driver.get('https://opensea.io/asset/create')
    
#####BUTTON ZONE#######
open_browser = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Open OpenSea Tab", command=open_chrome_profile) #executes the function when clicked
open_browser.grid(row=22, column=1)
#####BUTTON ZONE END#######
root.mainloop()
```

*The problem is that it is not working as expected at all*:

First, after clicking the `Open OpenSea Tab` button, the program DOES open a chrome window with my user data and default profile, but it doesn't go to the link provided (`'https://opensea.io/asset/create'`).

And second, it also crashes the GUI without throwing any errors, and even worse, it crashes the Spyder Kernel too!

[image: problem]

I'm very confused, to me it doesn't seem I have done any illegal stuff here, but I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain me how should I patch this issue?

I managed to build the code above following the recommendations from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975615/use-default-chrome-profile-with-selenium-in-python?rq=1), but I never expected ending up with a weird problem like this one in the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- You need to remove `Default` from the profile PATH. So effectively your line of code will be:

  ```
  opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir=r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #PATH profile
  ```

> You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:
>
> - [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
> - [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed with ChromeDriver and Selenium
>   in
>   Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112188/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-fa/52112468#52112468)
> - [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

- You need to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) within `Service()` as follows:

  ```
  s = Service('C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Comment: Thank you based god, these 2 things definitely patched the issue! If you don't mind, I have still a minor question left, which is, if I'm planning to build an executable file with this program, will that executable file include the ```chromedriver.exe``` from my machine and use it correctly in another PC after that user double-clicks the executable file?

Comment: @NoahVerner Feel free to raise a new question with all the details and incase of emergency you may like to discuss in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Will do for sure! Again, thanks for your help @undetected Selenium